# How can I execute a PHP file before using its content with another file?

Tags: php, html, css, variables

### Situation

I’m mixing HTML & CSS with PHP variables, so that I can manage a lot of settings with just one config file. This is all working fine, but I’m trying to merge and minify the CSS now. And this causes a problem.

---

### Problem

The variables won’t be echoed into the compressed sheet because the PHP script won't be executed. And that is because file_get_contents() converts the content into a string.

---

### Question

Is it in some way possible to execute the files first, and then grab their contents? Or grab their contents in another way, a way that they still will be executed?

---

### Files

*config.php*

```
$priColor = '#000';
```

*base-stylesheet.php*

```
/* CSS header defined */
/* config.php included */
body{
    background-color: <?= $priColor ?>;
}
```

*specific-stylesheet.php*

```
/* CSS header defined */
/* config.php included */
.site-specific-element{
    background-color: <?= $priColor ?>;
}
```

*minified-stylesheets.php*

```
// Set files that must be minified
$cssFiles = array(
    "base-styleseet.php",
    "specific-stylesheet.php"
);

// Get those files
$buffer = "";
foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
    $buffer .= file_get_contents($cssFile);
}

// Minify and echo them
minifyCSS($buffer);
echo $buffer;
```

*index.php*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="minified-stylesheets.php">
```

Comment: Doesn't `$priColor = #000;` get commented out after `#`?

Comment: No in the actual files I use quotes, forgot them in this example. Edited now. The CSS/PHP mix is working with single files. But not when merging and compressing them.

Comment: Why not make an associate array with whatever settings you wish and `include` it.

Comment: Instead of `file_get_contents`, you **MUST** use one of the following: `include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once`.

Comment: Yes true, I will. But only using include or require is not enough. That wouldn't let me minify it. The way Ease Technology describes does, and the way Ben describes in his comment on Styphon's answer, is, I think, even more powerful.

Comment: I got a small delay while editing the comment. It had enough content to be an useful answer. And so, I answered the question with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are familiar with the `ob_start()` method.

But I will show a better alternative (and faster):

Your main file:

```
$cssFiles = array(
    "base-styleseet.php",
    "specific-stylesheet.php"
);

$buffer = "";
foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
    $buffer .= include($cssFile);
}

minifyCSS($buffer);
echo $buffer;
```

Well, nothing much here. Just added a `include()` there...

But it won't work as intended, unless you do like this, for every file:

1. Create a [heredoc](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) with all the content
2. Return it

Using the base stylesheet as an example:

```php
<?php

    //remember to escape the { chars        
    return <<<CSS
/* CSS header defined */
/* config.php included */
body\{
    background-color: $priColor;

    /* with an array */
    background-image: url('{$images['print']}');
    /* or */
    background-image: url('$images[print]');
\}
CSS;
```

<sup>* Ignore the broken syntax highlight</sup>

And you are done.

No more nasty `ob_start()`!!!

Also, CSS comments use the `/* */` syntax, `//` will be evaluated as an invalid CSS selector.

Comment: Wow, I'll dive into this! But assuming it works, I see why it's faster. Tx.

Comment: @PepijnGieles You're welcome. I recomment that you don't jump the accepted answer around without trying it yourself first. EaseTechnology's answer worked for you and you tried it. If this is actually better for your situation, you may accept it (if you like).

Comment: This however will take way more time writing CSS and will make it quite ugly and less usable for other people.

Comment: @PepijnGieles Therefore my recommendation to try it yourself first. To me, it is way easier to use and a lot faster.

Comment: Sorry for jumping around. I'll check what works better. Can you explain why I should prefer your answer? You mention the nasty ob_start(), but why is it nasty, and why more nasty than adjusting the CSS like you recommend?

Comment: @PepijnGieles Nasty because you are using it to go around the way the language works, in a not-so-good way. That would be the same as scrapping a webpage using a `include` to get the http content. Also, it may give problems if you use gzip encoding to send it (either automatic by the server, or set by `.htaccess`). For that, it will create an output buffer with the contents you `echo` to the browser. Now, imagine what would happen when we start messing around with output buffers...

Comment: @PepijnGieles Also, if the include fails for some reason (for example, you misspelled a file), you will be minifying the output of the error message. Now, you will see an extremely weird output in your CSS, and you have no idea what that is. What do you do now? Or imagine that a variable was misspelled or you forgot to set it. You won't be able to easily debug a code with a minified CSS content that also tried to minify some HTML in it. You can disable the error messages, but then you won't know if something is going wrong.

Comment: @PepijnGieles You're welcome. I really hope I have teached you something. As a bonus tip: when you include a file, you can return **ANYTHING**. You can return strings, numbers, arrays, objects... Anything! This is used a lot for configurations. For example: `<?php return array('print'=>array('background'=>'red','font-size'=>'1.2em'));`, which would pass the array for you to use. Example: `<?php $config = include 'example.php'; var_dump($config);`. Also, the missing closing tag was intentional.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to do is include the file into a PHP buffer and then minify the buffer

```
// Set files that must be minified
$cssFiles = array(
    "base-styleseet.php",
    “specific-stylesheet.php"
);

// Get those files
ob_start();
foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
    include($cssFile);
}

// Minify and echo them

$css = minifyCSS(ob_get_clean());
echo $css;
```

Comment: Great answer. And Ben's comment on Stypon's answer does the same, but only once so not every user's got to wait for the file to be produced. Even better for performance!

Answer (score 1):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will literally read the content of a file and place the content into a string. What you need to use is [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). This will parse the contents of the file.

Comment: But then I won't be able to minify the content anymore, will I? Cause it's already parsed.

Comment: Or parse them on a save action (e.g. in your CMS the styles are updated). Then store the parsed content in a file like `base.timestamp.css`. This way you don't have to always parse the CSS before loading the page, which leads to a faster loading time.